# Distinction or rule about $d$ and $\delta$ in differential forms

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, calculus-of-variations

I have in trouble understanding the differential forms.

For $k$ form $\alpha$ and $l$ form $\beta$ we have 
\begin{align}
\alpha \wedge \beta = (-1)^{kl} \beta \wedge \alpha
\end{align}
And for differentiation, we have 
\begin{align}
d(\alpha \wedge \beta) = d \alpha \wedge \beta + (-1)^k \alpha \wedge d \beta
\end{align}

Apply this for usual Riemannian case, for 1-form spin connection $w$, 
and two form curvature $R= dw+ w\wedge w$
\begin{align}
d R = d^2 w + dw \wedge w - w \wedge dw 
= d w \wedge w - w \wedge dw
\end{align}

Now i want to variation of differential forms. How about variation? 
is the same rule holds?

In page [10 of lecture note](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/research/gr/members/gibbons/gwgPartIII_Supergravity.pdf) and some computation in https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/222100/variations-of-actions-of-lie-algebra-valued-differential-forms, 
it seems they treat $\delta$, following usual Lebiniz rule.  $i.e$, 
\begin{align}
\delta R = \delta d w+ \delta w \wedge w + w \wedge \delta w
\end{align}

Is their procedure right?

In usual differentiation or variation case, this does not be a big problem,
(As far as i known, the role of differentiation and variation are similar whether they treat function or functional) but in terms of differential form. I got confused.

Can you give me some formula for variation $\delta$  acting on $(\alpha \wedge \beta)$?

How about Lie derivatives?

I tried to find some reference related with variation on differential form, but they only treat differentiation. Recommendation of any kinds of references are welcomed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what needs to be emphasised is that $d$ and this variational $\delta$ (as opposed to the codifferential $\delta$ that is the adjoint of $d$) are two very different operations, that both happen to be a bit like derivatives:

- Imprecisely, $d$ talks about the variation in the form $\alpha$ near $x$ as we move around on the manifold. A simple, though coarse, analogue is the derivative $d/dx$.
- Whereas $\delta$ is talking about what happens to a *function* of $\alpha$ if we change $\alpha$ by a small amount; I find the physicists' notation is rather lacking here. The (more precise) analogue is the functional derivative, $DF[\alpha](\phi) = \lim_{h \to 0} (F[\alpha+h\phi]-F[\alpha])/h $.

In particular, there is antisymmetry built into the definition of $d$, but $\delta$, while superficially looking the same, is an operation talking about different sorts of variations in a different place. A more mathematical way to write the variation is to expand $F[\alpha+h\phi]$ to first order in $h$, so, for example,
$$ (\alpha+h\phi) \wedge (\alpha+h\phi) = \alpha \wedge \alpha + h(\phi \wedge \alpha + \alpha \wedge \phi) + o(h), $$
and subtracting and taking $h \to 0$ gives Leibniz for the variational derivative.

Comment: Thanks your answer really helps me understanding differential forms. I noticed that Lie derivatives for differential form also obey Leibniz rule same as variation.